# Trace of product of squared matrix and positive definite matrix is nonnegative (short exercise)

Tags: matrix-equations, trace, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $\Sigma$ be a real $d \times d$-matrix and $C$ be a real, symmetric, positive definite $d \times d$-matrix. Does it then hold, that
$$ \text{tr}(\Sigma^2C) \geq 0 \quad ?$$

Comment: Try $d=2$, $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=I$.

Comment: The trace is then $0$, which is not a counterxample.

Comment: @Joker123 The trace is $-2$.

Comment: Such that you know. The example takes advantage that the algebra of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ is the same as that of the complex numbers $a+ib$. The $\operatorname{tr}(\cdot)$ on them is the same as $2\operatorname{Re}(\cdot)$. So, that $\Sigma$ is like $i$, $C$ is $1$, and $\Sigma^2C$ is $i^2\cdot 1=-1$. Since $2\operatorname{Re}(i^2\cdot 1)=-2$, that is why we expect that $\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^2C)=-2$.

Comment: The trace is now -2 after editing. Thanks for the counterexample!